"ask deploy" on Mac gives "Cannot copy '<project_directory>/dist' to a subdirectory of itself, '<project_directory>/dist/.ask' error
My Alexa skill builds just fine.  Unfortunatelly, when I attempt to perform an "ask deploy", it attempts to copy the dist directory into dist/.ask.
I've seen similar issues reported in github projects.  They attribute it to running on a Mac.
Does anyone know of a fix or see what I may be doing wrong?
dist (master) % npx ask deploy
Deploy configuration loaded from ask-resources.json
Deploy project for profile [default]

==================== Deploy Skill Metadata ====================
Uploading the entire skill package and building the models. Normally it takes a few minutes...
[Warn]: The hash of current skill package folder does not change compared to the last deploy hash result, CLI will skip the deploy of skill package.
Skill ID: <omitted>

==================== Build Skill Code ====================
[Error]: Cannot copy '<omitted project dir>/dist' to a subdirectory of itself, '<omitted project dir>/dist/.ask'.
dist (master) % 


I checked out the alexa/ask-cli repo from gitHub and found that the CodeBuilder._setUpBuildFolder() function has an issue... it's not behaving in the way it seems it was intended to behave.  It looks like there was an attempt to prevent the copy issue I'm seeing, but it's not working.
In some reading I've done, I've found that other Mac users are experiencing issues like this with copy routines.
I've got a fix working locally on my machine.  I'll clean it up and submit a pull request to see if it passes muster and can help other people.
